# Simulate Op-Amp low-pass transfer function in Python

Tags: python, transfer-function, frequency-response, laplace-transform

I am struggling to simulate the frequency response of a simple op-amp low-pass transfer function in Python. The results I get are not accurate. The transfer function is $H(s)=\frac{1}{1 + s\tau}$, where $\tau=\frac{1}{2\pi f_{cutoff}}$. So I would expect a frequency response with a gain of 0dB until the cutoff frequency, then -20dB/dec, classic. But as shown below, I have gain of $\approx -7.5dB$, and also the cutoff frequency seems to be off. What am I doing wrong?

BTW, in case you are wondering why I filter a sine-wave going through the PA - just to check that the filtered sine ends up on a single bin to have a "clean" result, I don't want any transients, thus the cyclic convolution (take-away from this question [Unexpected frequency components after applying bandpass filter in python](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/89311/unexpected-frequency-components-after-applying-bandpass-filter-in-python)).

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import convolve1d
from scipy.fftpack import fft
import control
from scipy import signal

# Parameters
f_in = 1e6
M = 64
f_samp = f_in * M
f_pa_cutoff = 10e6
N = int((f_samp / f_in) * 128)

# Signals and Axis
t = np.linspace(0, float((1 / f_samp) * (N - 1)), num=int(N), dtype=float)
x = np.sin(2 * math.pi * f_in * t)

freq_axis = np.fft.fftfreq(N, 1/f_samp)
freq_axis = freq_axis[0:N//2]

# PA transfer function
imp = np.concatenate(([1], np.zeros(len(t) - 1)))

pa_tau = 1 / (2 * math.pi * f_pa_cutoff)
pa_gain = 1
pa_tf_vec = ([0, pa_gain], [pa_tau, 1])

_, sig_opamp_imp_resp, _ = signal.lsim(pa_tf_vec, U=imp, T=t)
y = convolve1d(x, np.array(sig_opamp_imp_resp), mode='wrap')

# Plot FFT
fft_x = 20*np.log10(np.divide(np.abs(fft(x)), N/2))[0:N//2]
fft_y = 20*np.log10(np.divide(np.abs(fft(y)), N/2))[0:N//2]
fft_opamp_filt = 20*np.log10(np.abs(fft(sig_opamp_imp_resp)))[0:N//2]

plt.figure()
plt.semilogx(freq_axis, fft_opamp_filt, label = 'PA TF', color='green', linestyle='dashed')
plt.scatter(freq_axis, fft_x, label = 'PA In', marker = 'x')
plt.scatter(freq_axis, fft_y, label = 'PA Out', marker = 'x')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('[dB]')
plt.ylim(-100, 5)
plt.show()
```

[image]